# Was Leonardo da Vinci homosexual?

Tags: sexuality, italy, leonardo-da-vinci

I have heard it a lot and read somewhere that he was homosexual like one of answers under the same question [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130328130002AALWIqq):

> It's rather possible. He had been charged sometime in the late 1400's with sodomy as well as three other men. With the exception of Beatrice and Isabella Este, {two sisters, one of whom he painted, Isabella} it has been said that Leonardo had no close relationships with women and kept his private life rather to himself. In the 16th century many speculated about Leonardo de Vinci's sexuality and possible sexual encounters with his pupils, Salai and Melzi.

I found it doubtful as there is not any accurate reference in the claim.

Comment: @Skliwz You are right. And one thing interesting to know that this edit rescued my question of being filtered by Iranian authorities of internet in Iran! I didn't have an access to my own question after creating it and when I wanted to edit it myself it was blocked! It seems the word homosexual is not as known as gay for FATA police of Iran yet!.. :))

Comment: For what it's worth, when I was on a tour of the Vatican, the guide pointed to one of Leonardo's paintings and remarked that it was clear he'd never seen a naked woman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there is a lot of speculation, we will never know for sure. What evidence there is, is pure speculation, but it does make a decent circumstantial case:

[I think this is a good setup:](http://www.bnl.gov/bera/activities/globe/leonardo_da_vinci.htm)

> The second major implication of the sodomy case is, of course, the
>   question of Leonardo's sexuality. Homosexuality was common in
>   quatrocento Florence, and several things indicate that Leonardo was
>   probably gay. He never married or showed any (recorded) interest in
>   women; indeed, he wrote in his notebooks that male-female intercourse
>   disgusted him. His anatomical drawings naturally include the sexual
>   organs of both genders, but those of the male exhibit much more
>   extensive attention. Finally, Leonardo surrounded himself with
>   beautiful young male assistants, such as Salai and Melzi.

The sodomy case does not appear to be disputed, but why Leonardo was arrested for it is. Perhaps it was as much about politics as it was about his sexuality.

Freud also believed Da Vinci was homosexual, and although he tended to think every man and woman had an obsession with phallic objects, [it is worth reading some of his reasoning.](http://www.bartleby.com/277/2.html)

> The situation contained in the phantasy, that a vulture opened the
>   mouth of the child and forcefully belabored it with its tail,
>   corresponds to the idea of fellatio, a sexual act in which the member
>   is placed into the mouth of the other person. Strangely enough this
>   phantasy is altogether of a passive character; it resembles certain
>   dreams and phantasies of women and of passive homosexuals who play the
>   feminine part in sexual relations.